# Efficient way to access submatrices with single index

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, submatrix

I'm trying to perform a strided access to a submatrix with a single index. I need this for a library I'm working on which uses expression templates. I have worked out the following class, where the access is performed by the overloaded `operator[]`, see below:

```
template <class A, class Type>
class SubMatrixExpr
{
    private:
        int Rows_;              // Rows of the SubMatrix
        int Columns_;           // Columns of the SubMatrix
        int Rows_up_;               // Rows of the original Matrix
        int Columns_up_;            // Columns of the original Matrix
        int a_, c_;                 // Starting indices of the SubMatrix as evaluated in the original Matrix
        int rowstep_, columnstep_;      // Stride along rows and columns for the original matrix
        A M_;

    public:
        SubMatrixExpr(A &M, int Rows_up, int Columns_up, int Rows, int Columns, int a, int rowstep, int c, int columnstep) : 
           a_(a), c_(c), M_(M), 
           Rows_(Rows), 
           Columns_(Columns), 
           Rows_up_(Rows_up), Columns_up_(Columns_up), 
           rowstep_(rowstep), columnstep_(columnstep) { }

           inline const Type& operator[](const int i) const
           {
               const int LocalRow = i/Columns_;         
               const int LocalColumn = i%Columns_;      
               const int GlobalRow = a_+rowstep_*LocalRow;          
               const int GlobalColumn = c_+columnstep_*LocalColumn;
               return M_[IDX2R(GlobalRow,GlobalColumn,Columns_up_)];
           }

           inline Type& operator[](const int i) 
           {
              // Similar to above   
           }

 };
```

where

```
#define IDX2R(i,j,N) (((i)*(N))+(j))
```

The overloaded `operator[]` works correctly, but is computationally very expensive.

*Is there any way to better implement the overloaded `operator[]`?*

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: no. (unless Columns_ is a power of 2). access with operator[y]operator[x] or operator (x,y) should be more intuitive with matrices

Comment: I'm surprised that the use of ``%`` is specially slow. I would think that the compiler is able to optimize and get both quotient and rest from one **one** division. Did you really profile the code ?

Comment: @hivert Not really, I had only a light profiling. But this submatrix access was the bottlneck of my approach. Therefore, I created other classes to cope with, for example, the case when entire rows (instead of real submatrices) should be accessed. In some restricted number of cases, though, I still have to use `SubMatrixExpr`. I have edited my post to fix the ambiguous statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you may got speedup is if you now the size of the matrices and sub-matrices at **compile time**. Then using template / constexpr may speedup things. For example if the size is known to be a power of 2 at compile time, the compiler will be able to replace division by shift.